# bitmap dump of a AlertDialog in android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I'm trying to take a screenshot using `getDrawingCache()` of the current view in my app and that is working fine. however, when **I grab the bitmap** it is missing the AlertDialog that I see on the screen.

Is there a way **to draw that AlertDialog on a Canvas to add to the bitmap?** Is there a better way of doing what I want?

I could not find any access to any sort of DrawingCache for the AlertDialog itself and can't really figure out how I could get that AlertDialog using getViewById.

Can someone point me in the right direction, as of now all my searches have turned up very little other than some people saying that I need to root the phone to do that. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.